# Linear combination of cosines

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a set of $N$ different angles $\{\theta_n\}_{n=1}^N$ where $\theta_n\neq\pi/2+\pi k$, how do I prove that $\Sigma_n(a_ncos(\theta_n))=0$ if and just if $a_n=0$ for all n?

Comment: That's not true. $\theta_2 = \theta_1 + \pi$. Then $a_1=a_2=1$ will work.

Comment: Or for any $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, take $a_1 = \cos(\theta_2)$ and $a_2 = -\cos(\theta_1)$.